# Converting unquoted strings to JsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

In our system we are parsing incoming messages with Jackson:

```
public JsonNode parseMessage(MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
    return mapper.readTree(message.getPayload())
}
```

This works for us because so far the external systems we are using were sending only valid JSON objects. However an other 3rd party system we want to support sends messages that may contain only a bare, unquoted string, e.g. `on`.

We want to process these messages the same way as any other JSON, but with unquoted strings Jackson throws this exception

```
Unrecognized token 'on': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"on"; line: 1, column: 3]
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'on': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"on"; line: 1, column: 3]
```

We tried using different parser features, but none seemed to work.

`Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES` would only work with field names and not values, and the rest of the possible configuration features seem to be irrelevant to this problem.

Our current workaround is catching the exception and adding quotes to the beginning and the end of the payload, but as this would hide other potential parsing issues it is not ideal.

Any advice on how to handle bare strings with Jackson?

Comment: Could you share an example of "unquoted" JSON you're running into? I can't picture it

Comment: The message payload we receive is simply `on`. Ideally we'd receive `"on"`, which is fine, since it is considered a valid JSON string, but we receive it without quotes

Comment: So basically you're not receiving JSON, that's the issue. You're trying to parse something that's not JSON and hoping Jackson will infer that it's a string. But it isn't. I think the only option is to check the first character. If it's not any of `" ' { [` then surround with double quotes.